# How to save and recall settings?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'll probably get hammered for asking this, anyways, I searched and didn't find much.

In a 3D world, after the user finishes zooming, panning, rotating an object, is there a standard way to save the view settings so if

1. program is interrupted, paused or
2. user turns off device
3. unexpected power outage/glitch (save system state every X minutes)

the view can be recalled?

Would the settings be saved in a plist? or shove everything in the AppDelegate?

I haven't worked with the AppDelegate much so does anyone have some sample code or can point to something on github if this is the case?  a tutorial?

Thanks

Comment: Is the problem just saving any piece of data or is it getting the current transform of the point of view?

Comment: It's both.  I probably should have split this into two questions.  My 3d object is built and all works but before I wander off into the Scenekit/AppDelegate/plist wilderness, I would like some advice.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get persistent storage is to use NSUserDefaults, but it sounds like you may want something that helps with core data like [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord)

Comment: Do you know of good example in Swift that deals with NSUserDefaults and the AppDelegate?